# how to see my service provider and identity provider in database when i have added by using webservices

Tags: soap, wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I am using an automation process presently.i have configured my service provider and identity provider by using the Ui successfully it is reflecting to database in these case my db is h2. But now i am trying to create the service provider and identity provider by using the webservice api of wso2is and testing by using soapUi.

My soap request is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://dto.saml.sso.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:addRPServiceProvider>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:spDto>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:assertionConsumerUrl>http://localhost:8080/travelocitysoap.com/home.jsp</xsd1:assertionConsumerUrl>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:certAlias>wso2carbon.cert</xsd1:certAlias>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:doSignAssertions>true</xsd1:doSignAssertions>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:doSignResponse>true</xsd1:doSignResponse>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:doSingleLogout>true</xsd1:doSingleLogout>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:issuer>travelocitysoap.com</xsd1:issuer>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:nameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</xsd1:nameIDFormat>
         </xsd:spDto>
      </xsd:addRPServiceProvider>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

which successfully created the application and in the wso2is console the response is added successfully service provider of travelocitysoap.com.but when i am trying to see my service provider in dashboard it is not visibe to me.and it is not reflecting to the database which i am using as h2.
    But when i am running the application it is successfully running.But i dont know where my service provider is storing in database of which table.

Where to add Service Provider ID so that I can view in the database with its name. Also please help me with the approach to automate Identity Provider.What am i misinterpreting.

Thanks in advance,
Vijay.

Answer (score 1):

Service provider is stored in registry db, You can view your service providers by navigating to /_system/config/repository/identity/SAMLSSO in admin console.Properties tab will have all the properies of particular SP.

If you want to view the SP in admin console follow the steps given in [1]

1.https://shivabalachandran.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/quick-note-4-creating-a-sso-service-provider-through-admin-services-wso2-is-admin-services-sso/

Comment: Also if you want to get the authenticated IDP name , select the option " Always send back the authenticated list of identity providers" in  "Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration"

Comment: hi Jenananthan,                                                                                              Thanku for the information.the idp whatever i have created it is not showing in the database.let us assume if i need to call the external service like google,facebook which i have configured in the idp by using the fedrated authenticators in that i have configured  oauth2 openid.now in service provider i need to call the idp by using the local and out bound authentication of the advanced configuration in which i have add my idp instead of the default one.now i need to call that idp.